# Start selenium grid (hub and 3 nodes) using single windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, selenium, selenium-grid

I would like to know what is the most efficient and easy way to start Selenium grid with Hub and 3 Nodes(IE node, FF node and chrome node).

For example can I do it by running a single batch file which opens up multiple cmd prompts and each cmd prompt runs its respective selenium node registration config?

At the moment I am starting it using 4 cmd prompts and registering the nodes with parameters in each cmd prompt respectfully.

Note: I am running Windows 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this you can just put all your cmd commands to one *.bat file and all commands will executed. File contents fot hub and 2 nodes (to create more nodes just copy and past and change port) will be something like this:

```
cmd /C start/MIN java -jar D:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -port 4445 -timeout 3000 -browserTimeout 3600

cmd /C start/MIN java -jar D:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=D:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe -hub http://localhost:4445/grid/register -port 5696

cmd /C start/MIN java -jar D:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=D:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe -hub http://localhost:4445/grid/register -port 5697
```

But it will be different cmd windows not the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm. Seems I was missing the "start/MIN" part.